# Suppressing Symbol Package Prefixes (Common Lisp)

Tags: package, common-lisp, symbols

When printing out object names which are interned in one package, but referenced from another package, the print name will include the full package name. For example, the following interaction interns the symbol X in PKG1, and prints its value from CL-USER:

```
* *package*
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">

* (defpackage :pkg1 (:use :cl))
#<PACKAGE "PKG1">

* (in-package :pkg1)
#<PACKAGE "PKG1">

* (defvar x '(a b c))
X

* (in-package :cl-user)
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">

* pkg1::x
(PKG1::A PKG1::B PKG1::C)
```

Sometimes for diagnostic/debugging reasons, I would like to printout external symbols without their package prefixes. In this case the printout would then look like (A B C). For complicated or nested objects where you know what the names mean, the package prefixes can make the printout hard to read, especially if there are multiple packages. Can the prefixes be temporarily suppressed for printout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can elide the prefixes of one package by temporarily binding `*package*` to it for the printout.

Example:

```
(let ((*package* (find-package :pkg1)))
  (print pkg1:*x*))
```

Since `*package*` is *globally dynamic*, this affects everything called inside (i. e. in the dynamic extent of its invocation) this `let` form but doesn't affect anything outside.